# why sometime variable are used as condition in if statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

e.g if(variable name) or
`var x;if(x){some code} else{some code}`
I understand
`if(x>7)`
conditions but only variable name inside bracket followed by if does not make me any sense.

Comment: this variable contains true or false

Comment: @AhmedSalameh ``if (x) { }`` also works when ``x`` is not a ``bool``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here variable can be a boolean value or sometime to check variable existence you check it in if statement. Condition you might test with if statement.

1. Element exist or not
2. Input value empty or not
3. collection length zero or greater

So following code:

```
if(result){
   //do something
}
```

will cause false in the following condition(also called falsy):

- false
- 0 (zero)
- "" (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)

Answer (score 0):

Either they contain a `true` or `false` value or the `if statement` checks if the variable is defined or undefined or even null.

Answer (score 0):

`If` contains an expression. And a single variable is an expression that evaluates to its value. Hence it can be used in `if` condition.

Moreover, `if` extracts the the Boolean value of the expression. So any non zero variable becomes true and others become false. This helps to write less.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, if a variable has a value, it is true, otherwise, it is false.

For example, "", 0, -0, NaN, etc., all evaluate to false.

http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_booleans.asp

Comment: `-1` evaluates to `true` => `!!-1 === true`

Answer (score 0):

The value should first be converted to a `boolean` and this is how it's done:

`if (x)` means `if (x != 0 && !isNaN(x))` for numeric values

means `x != ""` for string values

means `x != null && x != undefined` for objects